# Как установить AvalonDock?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь прикрепить [AvalonDock](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=avalondock) к проекту. Там архив в котором архив с source code, как собрать и использовать в WPF проекте?

Comment: Как обычно.
Хотя, бинарники же есть... были, помню. Просто надо уметь искать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключите из [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Extended.Wpf.Toolkit/)

Вот актуальная страница проекта на github: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit